# Who are the Lions of Ariel?

Tags: tanach

Who are the Ariel lions described in 2 Samuel 23.20 - 1 Chronicles 11.22 killed by Benaiah? Men, giants or temples?

Comment: I think you mean the two Ariel of Moab. Typically they're understood to have been strong warriors or chieftains.

Comment: את שני אריאל מואב. כתרגומו ית תרין רברבי מואב והיא מלה מורכבת מן ארי ומן אל וארי יש לו גבורה ואל הוא לשון חוזק ואעפ"י שהיה בניהו כהן ואסור להטמא למתים להלחם באויבי ה' הוא מצוה כשצוה הקב"ה להלחם בשבעה גוים ובשאר האומות המצירות לישראל לא חלק בין כהנים לישראל וכן צוה להיות כהן משוח מלחמה ולהכנס עם ישראל למלחמה והנה פנחס טמא עצמו למצוה כשהרג זמרי וכזבי וכן הלך למלחמת מדין עם ישראל

Can you please translate Radak's explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the OP's request, a translation of Radak's commentary on the term:

> את שני אריאל מואב. כתרגומו ית תרין רברבי מואב והיא מלה מורכבת מן ארי ומן אל וארי יש לו גבורה ואל הוא לשון חוזק ואעפ"י שהיה בניהו כהן ואסור להטמא למתים להלחם באויבי ה' הוא מצוה כשצוה הקב"ה להלחם בשבעה גוים ובשאר האומות המצירות לישראל לא חלק בין כהנים לישראל וכן צוה להיות כהן משוח מלחמה ולהכנס עם ישראל למלחמה והנה פנחס טמא עצמו למצוה כשהרג זמרי וכזבי וכן הלך למלחמת מדין עם ישראל

Translation: The two Ariel of Moab. As the Targum [gave it], "two great ones of Moab" and [the word Ariel] is constructed [from two words]: From Lion and from El, Lion meaning that he has courage and El which is a term referring to strength, and though Benayahu was a kohen [priest[ and was not allowed to be defiled by dead people, to fight with the enemies of Hashem is a commandment commanded by the Holy One, Blessed is He to fight the seven nations and we see that Pinchas himself defiled himself when he killed Zimri and Cozbi and also went to do battle with Midian, together with Israel.

Comment: Here it says something else... שני אריאל מואב. שני גבורי מואב; וכן אמ' התרגום בספר שמואל (שם פס' כ) "תרין רברבי מואב". וכנה הגבורים "אריאל" לפי שהארי גבור וחזק, וכן "אל" לשון חוזק:

Comment: I don't know what the source is, but that's exactly the same idea as brought by the Radak.

Comment: It is always Radak. But this Ariel, of 2Samuel/1Chronicles is the same Ariel mentioned in Ezra 8:16?

Comment: No. That's a personal name of one of the heads of the Levites during the time of Ezra. In this context, as a Jewish name, the name would be understood more as "lion of God" rather than "courage and strength".